# Error importing JSON in 11.3 (worked in 11.2)

Tags: import, xml

**EDIT** : *Originally posted as an XML issue, file format was found to be actually JSON, yet the problem is essentially the same: Import worked in 11.2 but not in 11.3. As per Hans' comments, replicated in 11.2*.

This JSON file was extracted from PDF. In 11.2 import worked correctly (was able to save it as MX file).  (It’s available via this Google drive link since it’s over 10MB)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wFNeFwD1tLG4hFiz9vKpZxofpZBg95W/view?usp=sharing

Tried `Import` w/ no options, with option "JSON", "RawJSON", and "ExpressionJSON" - as well as `ImportString` - all failed in 11.3.

The original PDF is found [here](http://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/dictionary.pdf).

Comment: @alanccalvitti Are you sure what you posted to google drive is an XML file. It looks like JSON or JSON-like format.

Comment: In v11.2 `Import["DMAT201708.json"]` took ~14 sec to display the entire contents. Redundant formatting text abound.

Comment: Depending on version of Acrobat reader you should be able to save the pdf file to text. That particular file is throwing "Import::general: Expected cross reference table" error.

Comment: @Hans, that does look like JSON, but `Import` w/  "JSON", "RawJSON", and "ExpressionJSON"  - as well as `ImportString` - all failed in 11.3 But you were able to import as "JSON" in 11.2? If so, maybe I can just change the title XML-->JSON. (The redundant formatting is indeed there around every word, that's the way it was written).

Comment: Currently using 11.2. I did change the extension. Because of the dimensions of this list it does not display nicely. Mathematica struggles with formatting and display of the contents. The original PDF file is 1.47 MB, I was able to export to text at 773 KB using Acrobat Reader DC all on Windows. Export to RTF ballooned to 9 MB using Acrobat Pro on Mac.

Comment: @Hans, you changed the extension to .json or something else? And starting with the version that I linked or with the original PDF?

Comment: Yes. The first thing I did was to download the files you linked, Then inspected the .XML file in a text editor. I then tried to open it with various programs that can edit/open XML files, they all threw a error at line one. Some opened the file. Visual inspection lead me to believe it was JSON format so I took the file and just changed the extension from .xml to .json. And it opened with no issues in 11.2. The additional experiment are just suggestion that the json format is just too big for a pdf file that is only 1.47 MB. So try another route.

Comment: Mathematica does appear to be correct that this is not a valid JSON file.  The file is not valid UTF8 at position 100117.  However, correct != useful.  It would be nice if it could just skip over this error, as my text editor skipped over it, and go on parsing the rest.

Comment: How did you obtain the JSON? (How was it extracted from the PDF?)

Comment: @Szabolcs, someone else performed the conversion PDF-->JSON and we're trying to track down the method. Is there an option for char encoding that might make it work as in 11.2?

Comment: CharacterEncoding is the usual option, but it does not seem to work here. According to Wikipedia, valid JSON *must* be UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to fix the invalid UTF8 using:

```
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[_String, "UTF-8"]]
```

Then use `ImportString` on the result.

In your case:

```
In[13]:= importedjson = ImportString[FromCharacterCode[
    ToCharacterCode[
        Import["/Users/aarone/Desktop/DMAT201708X.xml", "String"], 
            "UTF-8"]], "RawJSON"];

In[14]:= importedjson[[;; 1, 1 ;; 3]]

Out[14]= {<|"number" -> 1, "pages" -> 394, "height" -> 1188|>}
```

Comment: are you using 11.3? I copy-pasted your code and using my local copy of that xml file I get this error: `Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character '?', at line 1:3`

Comment: Yes, I just checked and I did this in 11.3.

Comment: OS? I'm on High Sierra.

Comment: Same OS here.  I get the error you get when I try to import the file directly from the URL.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not using the URL, I have the local copy DMAT201708X.xml

Comment: Interesting indeed.  How did you save the file?  Using the download button in the upper right or cmd-s?

Comment: It's automatically sync'd by Google Drive. When I share the link, I imagine you are saving the exact same copy I have locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77886/discussion-between-aaron-enright-and-alancalvitti).

Comment: your UTF transcoding works on the .json version and "RawJSON" option and also on the XML version, thanks. I must have accidentally renamed them after sharing links.

Comment: Great to hear!  Have fun.

Comment: Is it worth asking about XML->JSON as a separate Q or do you know of a Mathematica built-in converter?